# Disputed post at SO, but it'd be great here

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, migration

[This post at SO](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1394623/can-i-dynamically-call-a-lgpl-gpl-software-in-my-closed-source-application) is currently being [disputed](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327056/can-we-rescue-the-information-in-this-question-somehow/).

**Short story:** it was linked from a [FAQ at Programmers](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7266/117353). It got deleted at SO. I pointed it out to the poster at Programmers. He's now asked for it to be resurrected somehow. It's off-topic both at SO and Programmers.

But, it's definitely on-topic here! I had a *very quick* search and couldn't see a dupe here, but we may well have one.

Do we want to agree to fold the information in the post into a Q&A here, either as a new one or as a modification to an existing one? I've posted this as a suggestion on the meta SO thread and linked here.

Comment: Just found [a meta post here from last year](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/a/257/4763) with a few more links to deleted Q's on SO. I can't view them on SO, but there's probably a lot more of this case. Not that we would have the time to seek them all out, but we could probably at least do something about the one being discussed on SO right now.

Comment: Some related posts here, but none are as specific as the one in question: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/gpl-interpretation-what-is-our-legal-exposure-if-we-include-another-projects, http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/what-are-the-arguments-for-considering-dynamic-links-to-constitute-derivative-wo, http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/how-does-the-gpls-linking-restriction-apply-when-using-a-proprietary-library-wi

Comment: This one might be a duplicate, dealing explicitly with the direct execution of FFmpeg: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4008/50. That said, although the situations are very similar, the misunderstandings being asked about may be sufficiently different.

Comment: I'm placing the migration tag here since it's prominently mentioned in the linked SO post :)

Comment: @apsillers I agree. Also, the SO post is very clear - even including the code he's using to call ffmpeg - which I think could be a very useful pointer in future. It's now reposted here: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/can-i-dynamically-call-a-lgpl-gpl-software-in-my-closed-source-application

Comment: Two more related questions, although still a bit different: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/can-plugins-for-closed-source-software-use-gpld-libraries & http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/can-i-use-gpl-libraries-in-a-closed-source-project-if-only-the-output-is-distrib

Comment: @TimMalone as an aside, I actually have an awful lot more rep on SO than I do on Progs. I was helping them out with some site moderation issues for quite awhile but SO is the site where I have (un)delete votes.

Comment: @durron597 Are you saying you wouldn't mind seeing if some more deleted open source related posts at SO are worth resurrecting here? If so, are [any of these](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/256/should-questions-regarding-licenses-and-usage-of-oss-from-other-sites-be-migrate/257#257) worth resurrecting? I can't see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In agreement.

It's on-topic, but again, migration can only happen with an SE employee. Someone can repost it at their will :)

Comment: Ok, done! http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/can-i-dynamically-call-a-lgpl-gpl-software-in-my-closed-source-application

Comment: I've only posted the Q and accepted A at the moment, I haven't read through the other A's to see if they're worth keeping. Someone can do that if they like, otherwise I'll find time to do it later on.

Comment: @TimMalone Hmm... I was kind of hoping to get a little bit more community input before anything happens, but heh. It's done now. I'm wondering whether we should toss the discussion over if these "reposts" should be under CW.

Comment: OH I thought saying 'Someone can repost it at their will' meant it was ok! Yes totally agree with CW. Making that change now.

Comment: I made the A CW but I don't have a checkbox to do it for the Q. Could you do that for me?

Comment: @Tim It's done :)

Comment: Thanks! Pinged you [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30735369#30735369) :)

Comment: Can you CW the question again? ArtOfCode undid it.. I've pinged in chat to ask why. I CW'ed the answer again but obviously can't do it for the Q :)

Comment: @TimMalone I undid it because there's no reason for it to be CW

Comment: @ArtOfCode Shouldn't I not be getting rep from it though, given I didn't write it? It feels a bit awkward to be getting rep meant for someone else - all I did was copy/paste and add a note/links to the start of the post

Comment: @Tim you put the effort in to preserve the post, no reason not to get rep for it. (Also, not getting rep is not a valid use of CW)

Comment: @ArtOfCode Ok, fair enough. Is there a SE-network-related reference for that? Not that I don't believe you, but two people have already said I should've made it CW, so I kinda need some way to explain it :)

Comment: @Tim There is one on Meta SE somewhere, but I don't really have the time to go searching right now. Sorry!

Comment: I've updated the link on the Programmers FAQ